# How to template an external ip from one service into another service

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

We’re using EKS to host our cluster and just getting our external facing services up and running

We’ve got external ips for our services using LoadBalancer type.

If we have a UI that needs an external IP address for a server. How can we assign this to the UI service without having to manually add it?

Is there a way to get the EXTERNAL ip of the a service in the config map of another

Answer (score 1):

`...got external ips for our services using LoadBalancer type...`

Your UI can refer to the "external facing services" using the service DNS name. For example, if the "external facing services" runs in namespace called "external", the UI can find the service with: `<name of external facing service>.external`, FQDN will be `<name of external facing service>.external.svc.cluster.local`